# What are the options to replicate Autonomous Database manual or automatic backups to other Availability Domains (AD) or Regions?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

Are Autonomous Database backups replicated by Oracle to other ADs or region or is there a way for the user to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Manual backups are kept wherever you decide to store them (i.e. you decide which Object Storage bucket in what region it needs to be stored). Automatic backups go to the Object Storage of the region; they never leave the region. Having said that, object storage is triple mirrored in every region, across ADs in multi-AD regions and across FDs in single AD regions.

Here's a sample Object Storage bucket URL that can be used for manual backups in Autonomous Database:

```
https://swiftobjectstorage.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/v1/namespace-string/DB2020AABAK
```

As you can see, the Object Storage bucket mentioned above is in Phoenix region and this URL can be used for manual backups of an Autonomous Database that is in a different region.

[The ADB doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/backup-restore.html#GUID-9035DFB8-4702-4CEB-8281-C2A303820809) has more details on the both manual and automatic backups.

Disclaimer: I’m a Product Manager at Oracle.